# Dask groupby and apply : Value error Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements

Tags: dask

I am trying collapse rows of a dataframe based on a key. My file is big and pandas throws a memory error. I am currently trying to use dask. I am attaching the snippet of the code here.

```
def f(x):
        p = x.groupby(id).agg(''.join).reset_index()
        return p
metadf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','p1','pd1','d1'])
df = df.groupby(idname).apply(f, meta=metadf).reset_index().compute()
```

`p` has the same structure as `metadf`. The shape of both the dataframes are same.
When I execute this, I get the following error:

"ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements"

What am I missing here? Is there any other way to collapse rows based on a key in dask?

```
The task in hand, to do the following sample in a dask dataframe
Input csv file :
key,c1,c2,c3......,cn
1,car,phone,cat,.....,kite
2,abc,def,hij,.......,pot
1,yes,no,is,.........,hello
2,hello,yes,no,......,help

Output csv file:
key,c1,c2,c3,.......,cn
1,caryes,phoneno,catis,.....,kitehello
2,abchello,defyes,hijno,....,pothelp
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `meta=` corresponds to the output of `df.groupby(...).apply(f)` and not just to the output of `f`.  Perhaps these differ in some subtle way?

I would address this by first not providing `meta=` at all.  Dask.dataframe will give you a warning asking you to be explicit but things should hopefully progress anyway if it is able to determine the right dtypes and columns by running some sample data through your function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that and it doesn't work. My functions might be just wrong. I am just trying to collapse based on a key. On pandas,  df = df.groupby(idname).agg(''.join).reset_index() works perfectly for my requirement. I am just unable to do the same on dask. I get numerous errors. Could you please suggest something that could work on dask?

Comment: I recommend creating an MCVE to help others easily reproduce your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added one above